# Searching string in a list of structure

Tags: c, search, structure

I made a list of structure and  with two string, now i want search and print teh structure which have the search string as substring in first string.
 My code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct test_struct
{
    char * first;
    char * second;
    struct test_struct *next;
};

struct test_struct *head = NULL;
struct test_struct *curr = NULL;

struct test_struct *create_list(char *first, char *second)
{
    printf("First structure %s: %s\n", first, second);
    struct test_struct *ptr = (struct test_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct test_struct));
    if(NULL == ptr)
    {
        printf("\n Node creation failed \n");
        return NULL;
    }
    ptr->first = first;
    ptr->second = second;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    head = curr = ptr;
    return ptr;

}

struct test_struct* add_to_list(char *first, char *second)
{
    if(NULL == head)
    {
        return (create_list(first, second));
    }

    printf("\n Added to list %s: %s\n", first, second);

    struct test_struct *ptr = (struct test_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct test_struct));
    if(NULL == ptr)
    {
        printf("\n Node creation failed \n");
        return NULL;
    }
    ptr->first = first;
    ptr->second = second;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    curr->next = ptr;
    curr = ptr;

    return ptr;
}

void print_list(void)
{
    struct test_struct *ptr = head;

    printf("\n -------Printing list Start------- \n");
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("Položka seznamu %s: %s\n", ptr->first, ptr->second);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n -------Printing list End------- \n");

    return;
}

int search_in_list(char *search, struct test_struct **prev)
{
    struct test_struct *ptr = head;
    struct test_struct *tmp = NULL;
    int found = 0;
    char *p;

    printf("\n Searching the list for value [%s] \n",search);

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        p = strstr(ptr->first, search);
        if(p)
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("Member of list %s: %s\n", ptr->first, ptr->second);
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    return found;
}

int main()
{

    char first[] = "54545";
    char second[] = "Big Boss";

    char first2[] = "78945";
    char second2[] = "Small Boss";

    char first3[] = "782355";
    char second3[] = "Medium Boss";

    char search[] = "45";

    add_to_list(first, second);
    add_to_list(first2,second2);
    add_to_list(first3, second3);
    print_list();

    search_in_list(search, head);

    return 1;
}
```

but thi code have a some bug I want to print 
54545 : Big Boss
78945 : Small Boss

but my code print neverending repeat the first line. Where I have a bug?

Thank to @Matthias I edit teh search function to

```
int search_in_list(char *search, struct test_struct **prev)
{
    struct test_struct *ptr = head;
    struct test_struct *tmp = NULL;
    int found = 0;
    char *p;

    printf("\n Searching the list for value [%s] \n",search);

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        p = strstr(ptr->first, search);
        if(p)
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("Member of list %s: %s\n", ptr->first, ptr->second);

        }
            tmp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;

    }

    return found;
}
```

and now It seems to print the members how I expected

Comment: The while loop within search_in_list() is an infinite loop if the substring can be found because "ptr" will never be NULL in that case. You can omit the "found" variable and just "return 1" after the printf() and "return 0" at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop within search_in_list() is an infinite loop if the substring can be found because "ptr" will never be NULL in that case. You can omit the "found" variable and just "return 1" after the printf() and "return 0" at the end of the function. – Matthias

Thank to @Matthias I edit teh search function to

```
int search_in_list(char *search, struct test_struct **prev)
{
    struct test_struct *ptr = head;
    struct test_struct *tmp = NULL;
    int found = 0;
    char *p;

    printf("\n Searching the list for value [%s] \n",search);

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        p = strstr(ptr->first, search);
        if(p)
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("Member of list %s: %s\n", ptr->first, ptr->second);

        }
            tmp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;

    }

    return found;
}
```

and now It seems to print the members how I expected – mardon